# Python: Add lists together

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to add the last four elements of k lists together element-wise given these lists have the same `i[0]` value.

`lst = [[1,1,1],[2,1,2],[2,2,1],[3,4,1],[3,4,5],[3,1,0]]`

`Output = [[1,1,1],[2,3,3],[3,9,6]]`

I know I should use:

```
from operator import add
map(add, list1, list2, ..., listk)
```

My issue if that there could be k-lists with the same `i[0]` value so I am not sure how to incorporate this element. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Are these lists sorted? Does the output order matter?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yep lists are sorted by `i[0]`. Yes, output order matters.

Comment: To clarify, Martijn is asking if the sublists are in order according to their first element, as in your example. The point being that if they are in order, the lists you need to sum will be contiguous. (But I see by the comment you left at the same time as this one that you understand that!)

Comment: Look into `itertools.groupby`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

[[k] + [sum(col) for col in zip(*g)[1:]] for k, g in groupby(lst, itemgetter(0))]
```

The `zip(*iterable)` call allows us to sum the group values per column; the `[1:]` slice lets us ignore the first column.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> lst = [[1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1], [3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 5], [3, 1, 0]]
>>> [[k] + [sum(col) for col in zip(*g)[1:]] for k, g in groupby(lst, itemgetter(0))]
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 3, 3], [3, 9, 6]]
```

Comment: Just to clarify the method.
1) Groupby i[0] for i in lst => `Itemgetter(0)` gives `i[0]` and the groupby will work on `lst` to groupby each `i[0]`.
2) groupby gives a new key each time the i[0] value changes so 1 is in it's own group, 2s are in their group etc. Each group has a key value.
3) zip all the groups together and ignore the first bit as we want to sum the rest of the values and then sum across each zipped group
4) Add back the first value = unique key from groupby.

Are the following steps correct, in terms of the logic?

Comment: @Blackholify: Exactly; the item you group on is passed on as the key `k`; this makes it simpler for us to provide the first element in the output.